# Javascript SLAP game to punish the unruly coder

Tags: javascript, jquery

My coders missed the deadline and our client is pissed,
is there any "slap the coder" javascript game I could direct them to, so they could vent their anger?
Kind of like slap the monkey, where you slap it with animated hand: http://www.suvi.org/funstuff/slapit.html
I would then put his photo instead of the monkey ;-)

Comment: Make the coders design one for you.